# how do i add objects to JFrames

Tags: java, image, swing, object, jframe

I am trying to make a game within JFrame but have run into a problem. I have created an object consisting of four images strung into one. My problem is, how do i paint this object in a JFrame?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

public class t4
{
    static boolean running;

    public static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public static double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    public static double height = screenSize.getHeight();

    public static int x = ( 250 );
    public static int y = ( 150 );

    public static final int sx = (int)width;
    public static final int sy = (int)height;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Image ur = new ImageIcon("redBlock.gif").getImage();
        Image ll = new ImageIcon("redBlock.gif").getImage();
        Image ul = new ImageIcon("blueBlock.gif").getImage();
        Image lr = new ImageIcon("blueBlock.gif").getImage();

        // Create game window...
        JFrame app = new JFrame();
        app.setIgnoreRepaint( true );
        app.setUndecorated( true );

        // Add ESC listener to quit...
        app.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e )
            {
                if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE )
                    running = false;
                if((e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)||(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT))
                    x-=10;
                if((e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)||(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT))
                    x+=10;
                if((e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)||(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP))
                    y-=10;
                if((e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)||(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN))
                y+=10;
            }
        });

        // Get graphics configuration...
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();

        // Change to full screen
        gd.setFullScreenWindow( app );
        if( gd.isDisplayChangeSupported() )
        {
            gd.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode( sx, sy, 32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN ));
        }

        // Create BackBuffer...
        app.createBufferStrategy( 2 );
        BufferStrategy buffer = app.getBufferStrategy();

        // Create off-screen drawing surface
        BufferedImage bi = gc.createCompatibleImage( sx, sy );

        // Objects needed for rendering...
        Graphics graphics = null;
        Graphics2D g2d = null;
        Color background = Color.BLACK;
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Variables for counting frames per seconds
        int fps = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long totalTime = 0;
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastTime = curTime;

        running = true;
        while( running )
        {
            try
            {
                //    wait(500);

                // count Frames per second...
                lastTime = curTime;
                curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                totalTime += curTime - lastTime;
                if( totalTime > 1000 )
                {
                    totalTime -= 1000;
                    fps = frames;
                    frames = 0;
                } 
                ++frames;

                // clear back buffer...
                g2d = bi.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor( background );
                g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, sx, sy );

                // draw some rectangles...
                /* int r = 45;
                int g = 232;
                int b = 163;
                g2d.setColor( new Color(r,g,b) );
                int w = ( 250 );
                int h = ( 150 );
                g2d.fillRect( x+25, y+25, w, h );*/

                if(y<775)
                {
                    y++;
                }
                else
                {
                    y=0;
                }

                // display frames per second...
                g2d.setFont( new Font( "Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12 ) );
                g2d.setColor( Color.GREEN );
                g2d.drawString( String.format( "FPS: %s", fps ), 20, 20 );

                // Blit image and flip...
                graphics = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
                graphics.drawImage( bi, 0, 0, null );

                graphics.drawImage(ur,x,y,null);
                graphics.drawImage(ll,x+50,y+50,null);
                graphics.drawImage(ul,x,y+50,null);
                graphics.drawImage(lr,x+50,y,null);

                if( !buffer.contentsLost() )
                    buffer.show();

            }
            finally
            {
                // release resources
                if( graphics != null ) 
                    graphics.dispose();
                if( g2d != null ) 
                    g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        gd.setFullScreenWindow( null );
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void wait(int x) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(x);
    }
}
```

i want to create an object containing images ur,ll,ul, and lr and be able to draw it on the screen.

Comment: i would add them into JLabel for example, why doing it so complicated?

Comment: @lum quest: If you find my answer helpful and it solves your problem, please click the check mark to mark it as the accepted answer. If I didn't understand or answer your question, please help me help you by telling me what you still don't get. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is what you should do:

1. Modify the class to make it extend `javax.swing.JComponent`.
2. Override `paintComponent(Graphics)`.
3. Create a `javax.swing.Timer` to manage the frame rate.
4. Override `getPreferredSize()`.

First (as requested by DavidB) I'll give you an explanation as to *why* you should do these things, and then I'll show you *how*.

## Explanation

- Since you're trying to add your component to a JFrame, you'll need the component's class to be compatible with JFrame's `add` method (actually, it belongs to `Container`, but that doesn't matter very much). If you look at [the JavaDoc documentation for `add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29), you'll see that it won't accept just any `Object`; rather, it requires an instance of a `Component` (or subclass thereof). You *could* subclass `Component` instead of `JComponent`, but `Component` is more for AWT applications than Swing applications.
  **In short:** Subclass `JComponent` so that `JFrame.add` will accept it as a parameter.
- Once you've subclassed `JComponent`, you'll need to actually tell the window manager what to draw. You can put drawing code anywhere, but remember that it won't be invoked (used) unless something actually *calls* that method. The method that the graphics environment calls to start the painting process is called `paintComponent`*. If you override this method, then the graphics environment will invoke your custom painting code.
  **In short:** Override `paintComponent` because that's what the graphics environment cares about.
- Since you're most likely going to be animating in your game, you'll want to keep a constant rate of Frames per Second, right? If you don't, there are many factors (computer power, other applications running, drawing complexity, etc.) that could make the frame rate go haywire. To do this, you'll want to call the `repaint` method a specified number of times per second (once every frame). This is the point of the Swing timer. You give it a block of code and a number of milliseconds, and it will run that code every time the specified interval has been elapsed.
  **In short:** Use a Swing timer so that you can keep the frame rate constant and controlled.
- Imagine you have a word processing application. It has a menu bar at the top, the document window in the center, and a toolbar at the bottom. Obviously, you want the menu bar and toolbar to be small, and the document to take up as much space as possible, right? This is why you need to have each component tell you what its size should be, known as its *preferred size*. Overriding `getPreferredSize` allows you to return whatever size you want, thus controlling the size of the component.**
  **In short:** Override `getPreferredSize` so that the window manager and graphics environment get all the sizes right.

* It's not actually `paintComponent` that's called; it's `paint`. However, the `paint` method calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder`, and `paintChildren`:

> This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected
>   methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren. They're
>   called in the order listed to ensure that children appear on top of
>   component itself. Generally speaking, the component and its children
>   should not paint in the insets area allocated to the border.
>   Subclasses can just override this method, as always. A subclass that
>   just wants to specialize the UI (look and feel) delegate's paint
>   method should just override paintComponent.

(source: [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29))

** Overriding `getPreferredSize` does not actually guarantee that that is the size at which the component will be shown. It merely specifies the size at which it *should* be shown. Some layout managers will choose to ignore this (such as BorderLayout). However, when you call `pack` to size the window correctly, it should calculate the preferred size according to this size.

## Procedure

### Extending JComponent

To make the class extend JComponent, just change the class signature to this:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyGameDisplay extends JComponent {
    ...
}
```

### Overriding `paintComponent`

You'll need to import the `java.awt.Graphics` class. See this example code for how to use `paintComponent`:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyGameDisplay extends JComponent {
    // Some code here

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // this line is crucial; see below
        g.drawString(100,100,"Hello world");
    }
}
```

**Note**: Above, I mentioned the necessity of  the invocation of `super.paintComponent` from within the `paintComponent` method. The reason for this is that it will (among other things) clear all graphics that you've earlier displayed. So, for example, if your program draws a circle moving across the screen,  each iteration of the drawing will also contain a trail of circles from the previous drawings unless you call `super.paintComponent`.

### Using a `Timer`

To get the FPS rate that you want, modify the class to include a Swing timer, as such:

```
// Include these imports:
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyGameDisplay extends JComponent {
    private Timer t;
    public MyGameDisplay() {
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        }
        t = new Timer(1000 / 30 /* frame rate */, al);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

### Override `getPreferredSize`

The reason for overriding `getPreferredSize` is so that layout managers will know how to properly size the container.

While writing the actual logic to calculate the size may be difficult, overriding `getPreferredSize` in itself isn't. Do so like this:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 400); // for example
}
```

---

When you're all done, you can just run the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyGameDisplay mgd = new MyGameDisplay();
        frame.add(mgd);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is excellent, but an explanation as to why some of these things are being done (in relation to Java's Swing library) would make it even better.

Comment: @DavidB: Okay, expanded answer.